# Что за ошибка unresolved function or method post()

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4

Код сервиса, выделяет красным метод POST и вэб шторм пишет unresolved function or method post(), но этот файл идентичный такому же файлу с другого проекта и там все нормально, то есть предполагаю что проблема не здесь, подскажите где искать (гуглом умею пользоваться и англ яз знаю - не помогает)

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class UserService {

      constructor(
          private http: HttpClient
      ) { }

      getUserByMail(email: string, pass: string){
        const body = {
          email: email,
          pass: pass,
          getUser: true
        };
        return this.http.post('http://ng-everyday/controller/user_control.php', body) ;
      }//
    }
```

Comment: При компиляции или в рантайме? this не потерялся?

Comment: Может быть проблема именно IDE, попробуйте Visual Code например , либо не все либы доехали npm i пробовали)?

Comment: post подсвечивается красным когда курсор навожу это всплывающая ошибка, а в консоли везде все ок, но и сабскрайб в консоль возвращает null

Comment: это проблема вебшторма, у них есть ишью открытый на их форуме

Comment: а что за npm i? не пробывал, я только учусь

Comment: overthesanity, так а почему он мне null возвращает если это не в коде дело?

Comment: `{ observe: 'response' }` сделайте и посмотрите что внутри объекта `HttpResponse`, `this.http.post('http://ng-everyday/controller/user_control.php', body, { observe: 'response' })`

Comment: в браузере ошибок нет в консоли headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://ng-everyday/controller/user_control.php", ok: true, …

Comment: но в вэб шторме такая ошибка при этом ERROR in src/app/shared/services/user.service.ts(23,83): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ observe: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [heade
r: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; }; reportProgress?: boolean; responseType?: "json"; withCredentials?: boo
lean; }'.
  Types of property 'observe' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"body"'.

Comment: вы в `body` смотрите) если будет `null` - значит сервер ничего не возвращает

Comment: объясните плиз, я в консоль так вывожу  .subscribe((user: User))=> {console.log(user); }; тут вроде боди и выводится

Comment: `By default the HttpClient returns the body of the response. You can pass-in an object with an observe key set to a value of ‘response’ to get the full response.`

Comment: без этого респонса я и получаю null

Comment: это слишком большая демагогия, [здесь вы найдете пищу для ума](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: спасибо не помогло. у меня просто эти методы не работают.